# How to make a parser for a web crawler maintainable

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri

I wrote a Ruby web-crawler that retrieves data from a third-party website. I am using Nokogiri to extract information based on a specific CSS div and specific fields (accessing children and elements of the nodes I extract).

From time to time, the structure of the third-party website changes which breaks the crawler (`element[1].children[2]` might need to be changed to `element[2].children[0]`).

So far, I have a utility that prints the structure of the node I extract which allows me to quickly fix the parser when the structures change. I also have an automated process that controls that it can extract "some" values.

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to deal with this issue. How would one write a crawler that is easy to maintain?

Comment: If you want to make it on an industrial scale, you can write a browser plugin and have outsourced workers click on the fields you want to scrape. It will then find the XPATH to those fields and extract the values. If the format changes, add a task (MTurk?) for a human worker to load the page and re-click on the fields to extract.

Comment: The answers given are excellent advice, however, without actual samples of the HTML you're trying to parse, we can't help you more than giving general/generic advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the data and metadata of the web page to find the element you care about as much as possible instead of using element index numbers like you are doing.

The "class" and "id" attributes are a good way to do it.  Nokogiri has XPath features that should make it easy to select elements based on those.  If that is not possible, you could try looking at the content of the page around the element, e.g. if you are looking for a weight and you know it is in a table, you could search for strings ending with "kg".  It's hard to give super-specific tips without seeing the document you are parsing.

I recommend that your crawler should check the data is retrieving and raise an exception (or show a warning) if the data looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS.
For example the price of a product will almost always be:

```
page.at('#price, .price').text
```

The site can change layout (theme) and this will still work.